# What should I know to develop cross-platform HTML5 game and compile it with PhoneGap Build

Tags: html, cordova, build, cross-platform

I'm thinking about developing HTML5 game to compile it with PhoneGap Build. I'm interested in the Android, iOS and Blackberry platforms. What I want to know is how can I handle different device resolutions with HTML5, what engine/framework is better for this? And are there any other things I need to know about developing a cross-platform app? BTW, for my game I don't need any native things like camera, accelerometer or anything like that, only touch controls.

Comment: The service looks to me more like an app server than an SDK or a build tool.  Do you have any experience in client/server scripting?

Comment: There are many hosting services that offer scripting support, what made you choose this one? You do not need a hosting service to write or test apps. You can serve them from a desktop while developing.

Comment: Get one each of the devices and start scripting for them. You will learn what is different.

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. This question is entirely too vague to be appropriate here. It calls for discussion, and can't be definitively answered. Please take a few moments to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to become more familiar with the types of questions that are (and are not) appropriate to ask here - that page clearly mentions that discussion-type questions (which include "What should I think about" type questinos) are not a good fit here. Keeping on-topic and specific helps keep SO an extremely useful resource. Thanks. :-)